Calculating shortest path between two points along a rail network
I would like to calculate the shortest path from mines to ports, along the rail network. Since the mines and ports are not directly on the network, I first worked out the nearest rail point for each mine and port.
However, I am now struggling to convert the rail network into a NetworkX graph and from there, calculating the shortest distance between each mine and port. When I ran my code, it is unable to work out the nearest path since all of the distances are zero. Please see below for the code I have written thus far. The rail network can be downloaded from here. I would kindly appreciate any assistance that can be provided. Thank you.
# Ports
ports = 
[{'port_name': 'Geraldton', 'geometry': POINT (114.59786 -28.77688)},
{'port_name': 'Bunbury', 'geometry': POINT(115.673447 -33.318797)},
{'port_name': 'Albany', 'geometry': POINT(117.895025 -35.032831)}, 
{'port_name': 'Esperance', 'geometry': POINT(121.897114 -33.871834)}]  

# Mine sites
mines = 
[{'mine_name': 'Gold', 'geometry': POINT (117.94568 -34.93467), 
{'mine_name': 'Silver', 'geometry': POINT (115.16923 -29.65613)},
{'mine_name': 'Bronze', 'geometry': POINT (115.11039 -29.51287)}, 
{'mine_name': 'Platinum', 'geometry': POINT (115.11130 -29.42621)}]

# Convert to GeoDataFrame
crs = 'EPSG:4326'
ports = gpd.GeoDataFrame(ports, crs=crs, geometry = 'geometry')
mine_sites = gpd.GeoDataFrame(ports, crs=crs, geometry = 'geometry')

# Column for nearest rail point
ports['nearest_rail_point'] = None
mine_sites['nearest_rail_point'] = None

# Nearest rail point
for index, row in ports.iterrows():
    port_point = row['geometry']
    nearest_point = nearest_points(port_point, rail_network.unary_union)[1] 
    ports.at[index, 'nearest_rail_point'] = nearest_point

for index, row in mine_sites.iterrows():
    mine_site_point = row['geometry']
    nearest_point = nearest_points(mine_site_point, rail_network.unary_union)[1] 
    mine_sites.at[index, 'nearest_rail_point'] = nearest_point

G = momepy.gdf_to_nx(rail_network)

shortest_distances = {}

# Calculate shortest path
for mine_index, mine_row in mines.iterrows():
    mine_name = mine_row['mine_name']
    mine_point = mine_row['geometry']
    
    shortest_distances[mine_name] = {}
    
    for port_index, port_row in ports.iterrows():
        port_name = port_row['port_name']
        port_point = port_row['geometry']

        try:
            shortest_distance = nx.shortest_path_length(G, 
                                                        source=(mine_point.x, mine_point.y), 
                                                        target=(port_point.x, port_point.y), 
                                                        weight='length')
            shortest_distances[mine_name][port_name] = shortest_distance
        except nx.NetworkXNoPath:
            shortest_distances[mine_name][port_name] = float('inf')  # No path found



"I'm strugglung" is not a valid question. [ask] and [mre]

What additional information do you need to be able to assist?

It's unclear if you need the shortest path between each mine and its corresponding port (at the same index) or among all ports. Either way, one option would be to use a primal approach (with momempy) to create the graph and compute the shortest_path_length (or shortest_path, depending on your expected output). However, before that, you need to snap the mines to the nearest rail boundary :
spots = (pd.concat([
    ports.rename(columns={"port_name": "spot_name"}),
    mine_sites.rename(columns={"mine_name": "spot_name"})])
             .to_crs("EPSG:3857"))

import momepy
G = (momepy.gdf_to_nx(
    rail_network[["name", "geometry"]].explode(),
    approach="primal", multigraph=False, length="dis"))

def nearest_bnd(p, ls, shp=False):
    sp, *_, ep = ls.coords
    nb = min(map(Point, [sp, ep]), key=p.distance)
    return nb if shp else (nb.x, nb.y)
        
coos = (spots.rename_geometry("geom_sp")
        .sjoin_nearest(rail_network.assign(geom_rn=rail_network["geometry"]))
        .set_geometry("geom_rn").assign(coo=lambda x: [nearest_bnd(p, ls)
        for p, ls in x[["geom_sp", "geom_rn"]].to_numpy()])
        .set_index("spot_name")["coo"])

all_spl = {}
for mn in mine_sites["mine_name"]:
    for pn in ports["port_name"]:
        try:
            uv = map(coos.get, [mn, pn])
            spl = nx.shortest_path_length(G, *uv, weight="dis")
            spl = round(spl / 1000, 2)
        except nx.NetworkXNoPath:
            spl = float("inf")
        all_spl.setdefault(mn, []).append({pn: spl})


{mn: min(d, key=lambda x: list(x.values())[0]) for mn, d in all_spl.items()}

# {
#     "Gold": {"Albany": 0.0},
#     "Silver": {"Geraldton": 117.85},
#     "Bronze": {"Geraldton": 117.85},
#     "Platinum": {"Geraldton": 117.85},
# }


